# How to execute code only when screen was made visible by changing the tabbar index, but now when another presented modal screen dismisses on it?

Tags: ios, swift

So my app is a tabbar application consisting of 3 tabs. What I wanted to achieve is refreshing the 3rd tab's screen when it was selected from the tabbar. For this I've overriden `viewWillAppear(..)` and added my code there.

But `viewWillAppear(..)` is also called when closing a modal screen on the already-presented 3rd tab's screen, or when selecting a photo while the screen is presented, and I don't want that.

Moving my custom code to `viewDidLoad()` also does not work because `viewDidLoad(..)` being called only once. (as I said, I want to refresh the tab everytime it is selected.

I've tried moving my code in a custom method called `initialise()` and have this method do the following:

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
            ((self.viewControllers![2] as! UINavigationController).viewControllers[0] as! MyCustomViewController).initialise()

}
```

but it fails because the UI elements are not loaded by the time I call `initialise()` and it crashes.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

Give the tab bar controller a delegate and implement this method: `tabBarController(_:shouldSelect:)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate/1621166-tabbarcontroller

It is called only and exactly when the tab changes by selection from the tab bar.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work because calling the "initialise()" method there would still lead to the screen not having its UI elements loaded, same crash as in the example I gave above.